# Entity framework relations, code-first

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to sort out the relationship between three tables.

Tables:

```
Director
```

1 director can "have" many movies. So in my db where I have many movies, the directorId can appear as a foreign key in several of them.

```
Film
```

Each Film have only 1 director and 1 review

```
Review
```

In this scenario there is just 1 review per movie. So i guess that reviewId should appear as a foreign key in `Film`.

The way I have it now:

```
public class Director
    {
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class Film
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int FilmId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Director")]
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
    }

 public class Review
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Film")]
        public int FilmId { get; set; }
        public virtual Film Film { get; set; }
    }
```

I guess the problem occurs when I try to add a second film with a directorId that already exits in another table. I try to hardcode it in Management studio but I get the following error:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key in object "dbo.film". The duplicate key value is(1)
```

Of course (1) is the DirectorId that already exists in a previous film.

I'm using Entity framework Code first and would appreciate help on how to set this up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Key` attribute from the `DirectorId` and `FilmId` in `Films` and `Reviews` tables. Because you defined a `Key` attribute for those tables (If you look at your created tables you can see those fields has primary key), so you can not insert two records with same FilmId\DirectorId in those tables

```
 [ForeignKey("Director")]
 public int DirectorId { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("Film")]
 public int FilmId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, that was it!